# Eclipse RCP: Bundle jar files to plugin and change them afterwards

Tags: eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, bundle, rcp

I'm using Eclipse RCP 4.3 and I need to bundle several jar files to a plugin, which I have to use in my RCP application.

For some reason I would like to change the jar files in this plugin after exporting it. When I export this plugin, it is more or less a jar file.
As jar files are zipped folders, it should be possible to switch jar files afterwards with another program (by unzipping, changing and zipping) right?
Do I need to register or name the file names in some meta data of this plugin jar file?

Answer (score 0):

If the jars you replace have the same names and same location no, if they have different names then yes. Look for references of your old jars in the .classpath file at the root of the bundle and you can see what you need to update.